# Error occurred while parsing request parameters. - Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api

so im passing a post method on the "charge" method i have but i keep getting 400 bad request.

This is the route and the input json:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/users/:user_id/accounts/:account_id/credit_card/:credit_card_id/charge'
Content-Type: application/json

{
"created": "8526798985", 
"amount": "2000",
"currency": "usd",
}
```

And this is the charge method:

```
  def charge
    transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)  
    transaction.credit_card_id = @credit_card.id
    if transaction.valid?
      transaction.save
      new_transaction = { id: transaction.id, created: transaction.created, status: transaction.status, amount: transaction.amount.to_i, currency: transaction.currency, credit_card_id: transaction.credit_card_id }
      render json: new_transaction
    else
      error_json = { error: "Invalid inputs" }
      render json: error_json, status: 400
    end
  end
```

also this is the transaction_params method

```
  def transaction_params
  params.require(:transaction).permit(:created, :amount, :currency)
  end
```

The error

```
Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:

{
"created": "8526798985",
"amount": "2000",
"currency": "usd",
}
```

What am i missing here? I did another api and this worked fine

Comment: Your JSON does not have the `transaction` node required as a wrapper per your `transaction_params`

Comment: You should use `if transaction.save` instead of `.valid?` as the later does not ensure that the record was actually saved.

Answer (score 1):

Your strong params is expecting:

```
{
  "transaction: {
    {
      "created": "8526798985", 
      "amount": "2000",
      "currency": "usd",
    }
  }
}
```

But you are providing it:

```
{
  "created": "8526798985", 
  "amount": "2000",
  "currency": "usd",
}
```

One solution would be to change the way the request body is put together on your front end, or you can update your `transaction_params` to read:

```
def transaction_params
  params.permit(:created, :amount, :currency)
end
```